# ScrollViewer Adaptável

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Eu queria saber como posso adaptar o tag ScrollViewer as bordas do windows phone, para todos os tamanhos das telas. Quando uso ela só fica com tamanho fixo, quando usa outro tamanho de tela ela não adapta ao mesmo.

Comment: você está definindo os atributos Height e/ou Width para `Auto`?

Comment: Não, pelo motivo que como tenho um stackpanel que passa dos limites da tela do windows phone, tenho que limitar o ScrollViewer para que ele funcione. Então quem fica com o tamanho Auto é o stackpanel

Comment: Bem, programaticamente, pegue o `Height e Width` do StackPanel, e atribua estes valores ao `Height e Width` do ScrollView. Espero que resolva.

Comment: Mas como ele vai adaptar ao tamanho da tela?

Comment: Nossa, é mesmo. O StackPanel vai ultrapassar os limites da tela, então o Scroll também vai ultrapassar os limites se você usar isso que eu falei. A não ser que você verifique programaticamente em qual 'tela' o aplicativo está rodando.